# ICU Regex matching for non-digit and no whitespace

Tags: regex, icu

I am trying to help the readability in my terminal and thought I'd create a trigger highlight for when I use `binding.pry`.

The regex I used to match any `<% binding.pry %>` is:

```
(?i:.*<% binding.pry %>.*)
```

This works great, but wanted to take it one step further and only highlight the current binding.pry in the terminal (in case I may have multiples that display in the terminal).

How might I write my ICU regex so the following outputs correctly:

```
    64:       <div class="form-group">
 => 65:         <% binding.pry %>  # This one should match
    66:       </div>
    67:       <% binding.pry %>  # This one should not be matched
```

I know I want to match a string that includes the `=>` as well as the `<% binding.pry %>` but negate the whitespace and numbers. The closest approach I thought would work was `(?:\S+[^0-9].*=><% binding.pry %>)` but this unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I was able to get a match by using the following regex:

```
(=>.*)(:.*binding.pry %>)
```

This satisfys my intention to only match `=> 65:         <% binding.pry %>`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I understood your last paragraph incorrectly, `(?m:^ => \d+:\s*<% binding.pry %>.*)` should do what you want.

It only matches the `=> 65:         <% binding.pry %>  # This one should match` line.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/89kj3u)